# Why does deformation quantisation have anything to do with $\mathbf{E}_2$/little disks?

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, deformation-quantization

Kontsevich proved that any Poisson manifold $M$ has a quantisation $\mathcal{O}_\hbar(M)$: an associative algebra recovering the $\mathcal{O}(M)$ with its Poisson bracket by taking $\hbar=0$. Later he and Tamarkin [realised](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9904055.pdf) that the crucial step in his proof was secretly saying that the little disks $\mathbf{E}_2$ was formal, i.e. $P_2:=\text{H}^*(\mathbf{E}_2)\simeq \mathbf{E}_2$ as operads. This was applied to the $P_2$-algebra of polyvector fields on $M$.

From [nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Poisson+sigma-model), a physics heuristic for why 2d things show up is:

> it was shown that [...] the Poisson model of a [...] Poisson manifold computes the star product in the deformation quantization [...].
> One may think of this relation between the 2d Poisson sigma-model and quantum mechanics = 1d quantum field theory as an example of the Chern-Simons type holographic principle.

Is it currently known how to make this mathematically precise, or another way that gives a satisfying explanation why the construction of $\mathcal{O}_\hbar(M)$ should pass through $\mathbf{E}_2$?

Comment: Are you looking for a mathematically precise version of the nlab quote? (like a rigorous version of the argument in Cattaneo and Felder's paper which shows this?)

Answer (score 1):

On page 3 of [Operads and Motives in Deformation Quantization](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9904055), Kontsevich outlines how formality of $E_n$ interacts with deformation quantization. It seems step 1 is the answer to your question:

"STEP 1) On the cohomological Hochschild complex of any associative algebra acts the
operad of chains in the little discs operad (Deligne’s conjecture). This result is purely
topological/combinatorial."

In other words, although $C_*(E_2)$ is equivalent to $\mathrm{Pois}$ through the formality theorem, they do not automatically act on the same objects. In the case of Deligne's conjecture, we get a $C_*(E_2)$ action on the Hochschild complex, which is something like a homotopy coherent Poisson algebra structure. The Hochschild complex comes up in the discussion of deformation quantization because in some precise way it controls the deformations of the associative algebra.

I would also recommend reading the entire 4 step summary of the paper because it is very well written.

Comment: I think this isn't quite a satisfying answer, especially given that already a lot of this is in the body of the question. I imagine nowadays there's a cleaner way of expressing an answer, which is part of the point of my question. For instance: in the paper there's not a clear explanation of why comparing these two $P_2$ structures gives a h-adic quantisation that e.g. would make it clear how to generalise to other operads, at least $\mathbf{E}_n$, it's not clear how it relates to Kontsevich's Swiss cheese quantisation, etc.

Comment: @Pulcinella That's reasonable! I'm obviously not a mathematical physicist, but the question intrigued me, and even this much was actually new to me. Hopefully it is helpful to some others.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is helpful, but one common way of constructing $(C^*)$ algebras is by using twisted convolutions algebras of groupoids $G\rightrightarrows X.$ These look like
\begin{equation*}
(f\ast h)(g)=\int_{g_1g_2=g}f(g_1)h(g_2)e^{i\Omega(g_1,g_2)}\,d\mu\;,
\end{equation*}
where $f,h$ are functions on the space of arrows, $\Omega$ is a 2-cocycle on $G$ and $d\mu$ is a Haar measure. This construction (at least formally) makes sense on Lie 2-groupoids, with the domain of integration replaced by $g_1g_2\sim g$ (since composition isn't uniquely defined on a 2-groupoid).  What this means is that we integrate over all 2-morphisms in the nerve of the 2-groupoid whose corresponding 1-morphisms are $g_1,g_2,g.$

So far this may not look like it has anything to do with disks, but a Poisson manifold $(M,\Pi)$ has a canonical Lie 2-groupoid associated to it, as does any Lie algebroid. Its space of arrows are Lie algebroid morpisms
$$T[0,1]\to T^*M\,,$$ and its 2-morphisms are Lie algebroid morphisms $$X:TD\to T^*M$$ up to homotopy, relative to the boundary. Here, $D$ is the disk. There is a canonical 2-cocycle given by
$$
X\mapsto\int_D X^*\Pi\;.
$$
We can form the twisted convolution algebra now. The integral is over disks, which correspond to 2-morphisms in the groupoid. You might think that this twisted convolution algebra is equal to the deformation quantization, and this seems to be true in many cases. This construction is related to the Poisson sigma model you mentioned.